# variable suddenly returns 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

my variable directLinks gives me 'undefined' in Chrome's javascript console when i used it inside `console.log` but it was able to work properly in two other occasions as you can see below.

```
if (jQuery(this).isOnScreen() === true && directLinks.text() === "www.example.com")
{
    jQuery.ajax(
    {
        url: directLinks.attr("href").replace("www.", ""),
        aysnc: false,
    })
    .done(function(data)
    {
        console.log(directLinks.attr("href"));
        var test = jQuery(data).find("#left").children().children("div").eq(2).children("p").eq(1).children("a").attr("href");
        directLinks.attr("href", test);
    });
}
```

Comment: `aysnc: false,` should probably be `async`

Comment: While I don't exactly understand your comment, the variable is independent of the results of the ajax request

Comment: he said that you have typo in your definition

Comment: Wow, I stared at both of them for a minute and didn't realize the spelling difference...and surprisingly my script now works :D

Comment: Where is `directLinks` defined in relation to all this?

Comment: I don't think the definition of directLinks would have really mattered

Comment: Unrelated to the problem you are having, why are you doing a synchronous Ajax request? (Almost) never a good plan.

Comment: I don't wanna blast a website with potentially 5+ requests at the same time. I'm still testing and writing my whole script so maybe it'll change later